# Redirect not working after successful update in Vert.x web application

Tags: java, thymeleaf, vert.x

I am working on a Vert.x web application, and I'm facing an issue with the redirect after a successful update operation. Specifically, after updating a user's information, I want to redirect the user to the "/users" page, but the redirection is not working as expected.

Here is the relevant part of my server-side code for the "/editUser" endpoint:

```
router.post("/editUser").handler(routingContext -> {
    // Get the user ID, new username, and new password from the request body
    JsonObject requestBody = routingContext.getBodyAsJson();
    String userId = requestBody.getString("id");
    String newUsername = requestBody.getString("newUsername");
    String newPassword = requestBody.getString("newPassword");

    // Call the updateUser method in the UserService
    boolean updateSuccess = userService.updateUser(userId, newUsername, newPassword);

    if (updateSuccess) {
        // Redirect to the "/users" page after successful user update
        routingContext.response()
                .putHeader("Location", "/users")  // Specify the redirect location
                .setStatusCode(302)  // Use 302 for temporary redirect
                .end();
    } else {
        // Handle the case where user update fails
        routingContext.response().setStatusCode(500).end("User update failed");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried the redirect code from above and it works for me

Comment: code looks fine -- try ` routingContext.redirect(redirectURL)` -- also `editUser` is poor path naming for a rest api